datatables not refreshing when Datatables().ajax.reload() is executed
I want to reload the my datatable when a new date is selected in jQuery datepicker.  I have the following initialization code:
$(document).ready(function() {

 currentTab = "stopCodeList";


$("#stopCodeDate").datepicker( {
    onSelect: function() {
       changeDate();
    }
});

$("#stopCodeDate").datepicker().datepicker('setDate', new Date());

$('#StopCodes').DataTable({



    ajax: {

        url: "php/stopCodes.php",
        data: { stopCodeDate: $('#stopCodeDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val() },

        type: "POST",
        dataSrc: ""



    },

and in another module:
function changeDate() {

if (currentTab == "groupList") {
    $("#Groups").DataTable().ajax.reload();
} else if (currentTab == "loc31List") {
    $("#vips").DataTable().ajax.reload();
} else {
    alert($('#stopCodeDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val());
    
    $("#StopCodes").DataTable().ajax.reload();
}

}
When I select a new date in the datepicker, the changeDate module is executed (I get the alert), but the
$("#StopCodes").DataTable().ajax.reload();

seems to have no effect.

according to this post,
When defining data: as an object (as in my example, data: is only evaluated once.  If you want data: to be evaluated each time you call DataTable().ajax.reload(), you must define data: as a function:
 ajax: {

        url: "php/stopCodes.php",
        data: function(d) { 
             
            
                return {"stopCodeDate":   $('#stopCodeDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val() };


            },

        type: "POST",
        dataSrc: ""



    },

It is important to note that data: as a function is not standard jquery ajax, but a datatables extension.
